# git branch for multiple remotes

Tags: git, git-branch, gawk, git-remote

When running `git branch -r` I see the branches on my remote repository.
Is there a way to see in the same working directory, the branches of multiple repositories?
My goal is to create a file that lists all branches in couple of repositories, like this:

```
repo1:master,dev,qa,fy-2473
repo2:master,dev,fy-1128,staging
repo3:master,fy-1272,staging
```

So on and so forth.
I have this to print the branches the right way:

```
git branch -r | awk -F' +|/' -v ORS=, '{if($3!="HEAD") print $3}' >> repolist.txt
```

I just need to have this functionality work with couple of repositories without having to clone each and everyone of them for this single purpose.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your repos as remotes to your local repo with `git remote add`, then `git fetch --all` them and adapt your awk command to produce the result you want.

This command will produce the output you expect

```
git branch -r | awk '
    # split remote and branch
    {
        remote = substr($1, 0, index($1, "/") - 1)
        branch = substr($1, index($1, "/") + 1)
    }

    # eliminate HEAD reference
    branch == "HEAD" { next }

    # new remote found
    remote != lastRemote {
        # output remote name
        printf "%s%s:", lastRemote ? "\n" : "", remote
        lastRemote = remote
        # do not output next comma
        firstBranch = 1
    }

    # output comma between branches
    !firstBranch { printf "," }
    firstBranch { firstBranch = 0 }

    # output branch name
    { printf branch }

    # final linebreak
    END { print "" }
'
```

or as one-liner without comments

```
git branch -r | awk '{ remote = substr($1, 0, index($1, "/") - 1); branch = substr($1, index($1, "/") + 1) } branch == "HEAD" { next } remote != lastRemote { printf "%s%s:", lastRemote ? "\n" : "", remote; lastRemote = remote; firstBranch = 1; } !firstBranch { printf "," } firstBranch { firstBranch = 0 } { printf branch } END { print "" }'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add the repositories to the same working directory using [git remote add *name* *url*](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-remote/), then you will see all of them when you do `git branch -r`.

For instance:

```
git remote add repo1 http://github.com/example/foo.git
git remote add repo2 http://bitbucket.com/example/bar.git
git fetch --all
git branch -r
```

will list:

```
repo1/master
repo1/dev
repo2/master
repo2/featureXYZ
```

Comment: great. any advice on how to readapt my awk to fulfill my end-result?

Comment: @Moshe: Unfortunately I am not very fluent with awk.

Comment: @Moshe just accept my answer, there you have all the information you need. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

After you run `git remote add` to add all remote repositories, and run `git fetch` to retrieve / update information of remote repositories, `git branch -a` will show all branches, both remote and local. For remote branches, it will be shown in format as:

```
remotes/{remote_name}/{branch_name}
```